# ¿Por que cuando intento instalar el ssh en ubuntu me muestra error?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Intento instalar el ssh en ubuntu hago: `sudo apt-get install ssh`, me pregunta luego `Do you want to continue [Y/n]?`. Dígito Y luego me muestra el siguiente error:

> dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching
>   ttf-mscorefonts-installer:i386

No se instalo porque cuando intento iniciarlo con `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh start` me muestra lo siguiente:

> Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the
>   service(8) utility, e.g. service ssh start
>
> Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
>   Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start ssh

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no es un problema de programación.

Comment: Es de linux no es de programación, configuración de ssh, tiene que ver con linux

Comment: No está claro cuál es el problema, ¿quieres instalar las fuentes de Microsoft? No entiendo por qué. El paquete `ssh` ha formado parte del `core` desde el inicio de Ubuntu, no necesitas instalarlo. Por otro lado, te indican dos formas de iniciar el servicio, deberías seguir alguna de las dos.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, pero si revisas sitios web se instala en ubuntu

Comment: ¿Puedes ampliar la respuesta con la versión de Ubuntu que estas usando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buscando encontré algo que quizas pueda ayudar.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Y si esto no lo resuelve, entonces:

```
sudo dpkg -r ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```